# how to secure azure mobile service / html - javascript

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

When I call an oauth provider like gmail and I get the token back, how can I make sure that all future calls I make are from that same client that did the authentication?  that is, is there some kind of security token I should pass pack?  Do I pass that token back everytime?

For example, if I have a simple data table used for a guest book with first,last,birthdate,id.  How can I make sure that the user who "owns" that record is the only one who can update it.  Also, how can I make sure that the only person who can see their own birthday is the person who auth'd in.

sorry for the confusing question, I'm having trouble understanding how azure mobile services (form an html client) is going to be secure in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to figure this out as well, and here's how I understand it (with maybe a little too much detail), using the [canonical ToDoList application](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-get-started/) with [server authentication enabled for Google](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-get-started-users/):

When you outsource authentication to Google in this case, you're doing a standard OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant flow. You register your app with Google, get a client ID and secret, which you then register with AMS for your app. Fast forwarding to when you click "log in" on your HTML ToDoList app: AMS requests an authorization code on your app's behalf by providing info about it (client ID and secret), which ultimately results in a account chooser/login screen for Google. After you select the account and log in successfully, Google redirects to your AMS app's URL with the authorization code appended as a query string parameter. AMS then redeems this authorization code for an access token from Google on your application's behalf, creates a new user object (shown below), and returns this to your app:

```
"userId":"Google:11223344556677889900"
"authenticationToken":"eyJhbGciOiJb ... GjNzw"
```

These properties are returned after the [Login function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj554236.aspx) is called, wrapped in a [User object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/jj554220.aspx). The `authenticationToken` can be used to make authenticated calls to AMS by appending it in the X-ZUMO-AUTH header of the request, at least until it expires.

In terms of security, all of the above happens under HTTPS, the token applies only to the currently signed-in user, and the token expires at a predetermined time (I don't know how long).

Addressing your theoretical example, if your table's permissions has been configured to only allow authenticated users, you can further lock things down by writing logic to store and check the userId property when displaying a birthday. See the [reference docs for the User object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/jj554220.aspx) for more info.